# Error:(4, 14) java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig using Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova

I open Android Studio and try to build the project . its showing the message " **Error:(4, 14) java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig** "

Comment: try to remove cordova library from build path

Comment: I have downloaded Phonegap/Cordova and made a project from command line

cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
and built it

cordova build 
When i import project  in Android Studio and try to build it, it gives me this error

java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig

Comment: I removed ant-build and and gen folder from Cordova. Now has warning but build sucessfully.

Comment: keep going on happy coding :)\

Comment: Hope it will help who are working with AndroidStudio and PhoneGap\Cordova.. :)

Comment: So my answer is useful to you?

Comment: No need to Remove the whole library . Just remove the two folders in the Cordova Lib.

Comment: Ras, is it the best way of running a phonegap project in the studio ? did you find a better way of doing it instead of removing the two folders you mentioned.

Comment: Shamaleyte,At present i haven't got any other better way . Since its working fine for me.